# How can i disable a html control in the web-browser

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

Why i am not able to change the visibility/Enabled properties of `HTML` elements in the browser control. i am using the code as below:

```
  webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("myCombo").SetAttribute("Visible", "False")
  webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("myCombo").SetAttribute("Enabled", "False")
```

what i am doing wrong in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
 webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("myCombo").Enabled = False '<--- for disable the control
 webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("myCombo").Enabled = True'<--- for enable the control
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide an element use this:

```
webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("myCombo").Enabled = False
```

To show an element use this:

```
webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("myCombo").Enabled = True
```

Comment: style.visibility is not found